# Multiple selection UITableView without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When selecting multiple cells in my tabeview the cells out of view are being selected too. I understand that this is because i am reusing the cell and its maintaining its selection as i scroll down. I have found a few people with similar issues but cant translate their solutions across to resolve my issue. I have tried not dequeing a cell and just use:

```
 let cell = NewBillSplitterItemCell()
```

but get:

```
 unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the line:

```
cell.currentSplitters.text = splitterList
```

in the following code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        fetchBillItems()

        let cell: NewBillSplitterItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewBillSplitterItemCell") as! NewBillSplitterItemCell
        let item = allItems[indexPath.row]
        let numberOfSplitters = item.billSplitters?.count

        if numberOfSplitters == 0 {
            cell.currentSplitters.text = "No one is paying for this item yet."
        } else {

            var splitterList = "Split this item with "
            let itemSplitters = item.billSplitters?.allObjects as! [BillSplitter]
            for i in 0...Int((numberOfSplitters)!-1) {
                if numberOfSplitters == 1 {
                    splitterList += "\(itemSplitters[i].name!)"
                } else {
                    splitterList += ", \(itemSplitters[i].name!)"
                }
            }
            cell.currentSplitters.text = splitterList
        }

        cell.name.text = item.name
        cell.price.text = "£\(item.price!)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
            {
                cell.accessoryType = .None
                selectedItems.removeAtIndex(selectedItems.indexOf(allItems[indexPath.row])!)
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                selectedItems.append(allItems[indexPath.row])
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont quite understand what to do and any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Everything within cell is nil so it starts at cell.currentSplitters and then cell.name would get the same error if it got that far etc

Comment: what is `currentSplitters` in `cell.currentSpliiters.text`? Is it an UILabel?

Comment: yes, so is .name and .price

Comment: have you checked if cell itself is nil?

Comment: The custom cell has been initialized so it isnt nil , but the labels within it all display as nil in the debugger

Comment: something must be wrong with your custom cell class. I would use a `guard` when accessing the labels until the problem is solved

Comment: your solution below works the same as `let cell: NewBillSplitterItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewBillSplitterItemCell") as! NewBillSplitterItemCell` but brings me back to the original issue of when i select a cell it selects other cells outside of the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @Mike said, inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need an additional check because cells get reused.

Something along the line

```
let isSelected = selectedItems[indexPath.row].selected
if isSelected{
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
```

Same thing inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you should update the data source instead of relying on the `UI` of your cell for that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your **cell** is **nil**, you should use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("..." forIndexPath:indexPath) as! NewBillSplitterItemCell
```

instead of

```
let cell= tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("...") as! NewBillSplitterItemCell
```

This ensures that cell will never be nil.

Also, I would check if the correct **identifier** is being used in all of your .xib .storyboard files.